# Dynamic parameters for method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, dynamic-programming

I have some normal set methods for a class which i want to call from a dynamic context. But i am having trouble with building up the method call from variables.

Example code setters

```
def set_name(value)
  @name = value
end
def set_size(value)
  @size = value
end
```

Now i want to call these setter from another method. e.g.

```
def call_setter(variable, method_name)
      #vaiable could be FixedNr/String/boolean etc
      #method_name is a string which = 'name' or 'size' or ...
  set_name("Mike") # this works, however i
      # need to do it dynamically from the par, since it
      # could be set_name, set_size etc. I have tried:

      #This should create the correct look of the method
  method_call = 'set_'+method_name + '(' + "#{the_value}" + ')'

  send(method_call) #Gives error undefined method `set_name(Mike)' for MyClass
  eval(method_call) #No such method error
  method_call # doesn nothing

      #Another working undynamic solution
  m1 = 'set_' + 'name'
  m2 = '(' + "'" +  "Mike" + "'" + ')'
  m = m1 + m2
  eval(m) #This works.
end
```

I know why the working calls work, the /'/ inside ('dd'). But since it could be a number i.e. set_size(55) i cannot always have '' around the value. 
So how could i construct a string which calls my get/set methods? i guess it is this part ""#{the_value}"" which doesnt work as i would want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically how you would do it...

```
def name=(value)
  @name = value
end

def size=(value)
  @size = value
end

# or even easier since the above are just basic setters: 
# attr_accessor :name, :value

def call_setter(variable, method_name)
  self.send "#{method_name}=", variable
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much, saved my day, only regret i didnt ask 2h ago :P. I tried some similar way during this time but somehow got an error and moved on to try other stuff.. I tried to find what i did before so tried without self. and just use without #{} and that works to. So dont know how i tried it before, must have built the string wrong. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
method_name = method_name.match(/^set_/) ? "#{method_name}=" : "set_#{method_name}="
send method_name, variable
```

Comment: 1+ for working solution, however Sean Hills solution seems a bit cleaner.

Comment: Yap, I agree. I think the main reason my code is 'dirtier' is because I wanted to deal with both of the following situation: `call_setter 'Mike', 'name'` AND `call_setter 'Mike', 'set_name'` ... I guess I never fully trust my users to know what they're doing... :-p